# Substitute Javascript this to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Recently I decided to convert my code into typescript, which lead to an issue of substituting `this` from JavaScript to TypeScript.

here is the code I am struggling with. 
TypeScript:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

class FormAjaxSubmit {

    form:JQuery;
    opt:any;

    constructor(element:string) {
        this.form = $(element);
        this.opt  = {
            boxID  : "#info",
            invData: {
                tag    : "[data-invalid]",
                tagTrue: "[data-invalid='true']"
            },
            msg    : {
                success: "",
                field  : ""
            }
        };
        // Even Listeners
        this.form
            .on('focusout', "[data-invalid]", e => {
                console.log(this); // outputs form.ajax object instead of current field with data-invalid 
                this.formVisuals(); // this method needs to be accessible too along with function's this
                e.preventDefault();
            });
    }

    private formVisuals() {
    }

}


$(() => {
    // Finally, we kick things off by creating the **App**.
    new FormAjaxSubmit("form.ajax");
});
```

I understand why it happens as `this` is assigned to main class by typescript. So it simply creates `var _this = this` on the top level and continues using throughout the code which prevents me from using old JavaScript style like following:

```
$("form.ajax").on("focusout", [data-invalid], function(e) { 
     console.log(this) // it outputs the current field with data-invalid tag instead of the form object itself.
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

So the question is is the a way to substitute JavaScript `this` in typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function expressions exist in TypeScript too. They're not "old JavaScript style".

```
this.form.on("focusout", "[data-invalid]", function(e) { 
     console.log(this); // works
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically, don't use arrow functions in these cases.

---

If you want to use both the class and the element, then you could do this:

```
this.form.on("focusout", "[data-invalid]", (e) => { 
     this;     // class
     e.target; // element
});
```

Or if you want to keep using `this` as the element instead of the class you could do this:

```
let self = this;
this.form.on("focusout", "[data-invalid]", function(e) {
     self; // class
     this; // element
});
```

I would recommend keeping `this` as the class though and use an arrow method... it reduces confusion by keeping the meaning of `this` consistent.

Comment: That makes perfect sense but how can I access class methods within this  function if it assigns `this` to current function. I need to use both if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day. It so great to have smart people around.