# Converting "this" from jquery to typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript1.8

I have this bit of code which works.

I now want to use it in a typescript app.  I still want to use jquery, but I don't understand how to convert the use of `this` to what Typescript needs to work.

```
if ($(this).width() < 769) {
    $('body').addClass('page-small');
} else {
    $('body').removeClass('page-small');
    $('body').removeClass('show-sidebar');
}
```

In typescript, `this` refers to the current class.  What do I replace that with so it works as expected?

Comment: You are confusing `this` context. Assuming that code shown will be inside an event handler `this` will have context of that callback function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Substitute Javascript this to Typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783572/substitute-javascript-this-to-typescript) -- this will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still want to use jquery, but I don't understand how to convert the use of this to what Typescript needs to work.

Move the function out of the class and call it from the class. Alternatively create a `self` variable to use both `this`(class) and `this`(jquery).

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html#tip-arrow-functions-with-libraries-that-use-this